# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un elemento está visible con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ya que en *jQuery* es posible cambiar la visibilidad de un elemento, ¿Cómo puedo saber si un elemento está visible o no en tiempo de ejecución?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Es verdad que puedes usar `is(":visible")` pero por experiencia te recomiendo el uso de clases para que no tengas problemas a la hora de testear tus aplicaciones, ya que muchas librerías de tests no tienen los componentes que se prueban visibles y por mucho que tu componente haga `hide()` o `show()` jQuery seguirá indicando que no está visible, y el comportamiento de tus componentes será extraño. Esto me ha pasado con la librería de tests QUnit, de los autores de jQuery.

Lo que yo haría sería: `$el.toggleClass("hide")` o `$el.addClass("hide")`.

Y comprobarlo con: `!$el.hasClass("hide")`.

Además hay que tener cuidado al usar `is(":visible")` porque `visibility: hidden` u `opacity: 0` se consideran visibles ya que ocupan espacio en el layout.

Ten en cuenta que mi solución es para comprobar si exclusivamente el elemento está visible. Puede darse el caso de que alguno de los padres no esté visible y por tanto no se vea. Si quieres comprobar algo así quizás es mejor que uses `is(":visible")` o `!$(..).closest(".hide")`.

Comment: Además los elementos tampoco figuran como `:visible`s si están en animación de fadeIn/Out o slideUp/Down.

Comment: Este método podría fallar porque un elemento puede tener la clase `hide` y estar visible si hay otra regla que lo haga visible. Por ejemplo: `<div class="hide" id="midiv">A</div>` con el CSS `.hide { display:none; } #midiv { display:block; }`, el div tiene la clase `hide` pero es visible en el navegador porque la regla de `#midiv` tiene mayor especificidad.

Answer (score 44):

Puedes usar la función `is()` junto con el selector `:visible` sobre un objeto `jQuery` ya existente.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un `div` con `id`: `"elemento"` puedes saber si éste está visible o no de esta manera:

```js
var esVisible = $("#elemento").is(":visible");
```

Para mas información revisa la documentación de [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) y [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: No soy experto en jQuery pero, aplica la inversa también? `var estaOculto = $("#elemento").is(":hidden");`

Comment: @CésarBustíos si ya que internamente `visible` esta definido como `!hidden`: `jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !jQuery.expr.filters.hidden( elem );
};`

Answer (score 13):

Al igual que emplea jquery el selector `:visible` en [su ejemplo](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/#entry-examples), lo puedes incorporar en la misma expresión de búsqueda del elemento

```
var visible = $("#element:visible").length > 0;
```

o hacer un filtrado

```
var visible = $("#element").filter(":visible").length > 0;
```

Estas formas de filtrado de elementos son particularmente útiles cuando vas a iterar sobre una lista de resultados

```
$(".elemento:visible").each(function() {
    ...
}
```

Aunque si sólo necesitas una respuesta booleana, como bien ha escrito [Carlos Muñoz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-elemento-est%C3%A1-visible-con-jquery/38#38), puedes hacerlo así

```
var isVisible = $("#elemento").is(":visible");
```

Answer (score 8):

Podés usar lo siguiente

```
if($('#elemento').css('display') == 'none'){
   // Acción si el elemento no es visible
}else{
   // Acción si el elemento es visible
}
```

en el caso de que tambien queramos chequear la opacidad hacemos:

```
if($('#elemento').css('display') == 'none' || $('#elemento').css('opacity') == 0){
       // Acción si el elemento no es visible
}else{
       // Acción si el elemento es visible
}
```

Comment: También habría que mirar el valor de `visibility`

Answer (score 8):

Me vi involucrado en éste caso específico donde la solución inicial bastaría con:

```
if ($elementoDOM.is(':visible')){ console.log('el elemento está visible') }
```

PERO! mucho ojo que como decía un compañero en otros comentarios ésto no aplica para elementos que tengan la propiedad: `opacity:0`.

En lo personal lo más usado es con `opacity` ya que de tal manera se logra animar la aparición/desaparición de elementos en el DOM de una forma estética. Razón por la cual la instrucción precisa que me acaba de funcionar es:

```
if ($elementoDOM.css('opacity')==1) { ... } ó
if ($elementoDOM.css('opacity')==0) { ... }
```

tener cuidado de no colocar el numero (0,1) entre comillas dobles o simples!

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
let valor = false; // variable de control 
$('#element').on('click', function(){ // al clickear sobre el elemento

  if(valor == false){ // si el valor es false
    valor= true; // se cambia a true
    $('.sidebar').addClass('active') // se agrega la clase 'active' al elemento
  }else{ // sino
    $(".sidebar").removeClass('active'); // se quita la clase active
    valor= false; // se setea el valor a false, en el siguiente click entrara en el if
  }
})
```

Basicamente el codigo funciona como un switch entre 2 estados

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].