# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un elemento está visible en la ventana de visualización?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero saber si un elemento se encuentra visible en un momento dado en el *viewport*, es decir en la ventana de visualización del navegador, usando JavaScript/jQuery.

Por [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/33/250), sé que con `.is(':visible')` puedo averiguar si ese elemento está visible o no, pero eso no quiere decir que este dentro de la ventana de visualización (y por tanto invisible para el usuario), que es lo que yo quiero.

Por ejemplo: En el siguiente código se comprueba si un elemento está visible cuando se pulsa el botón; pero si realizamos scroll, bajamos hasta abajo de la página y volvemos a pulsar en el botón, nos sigue diciendo que sí lo está aunque el usuario ya no puede verlo.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  alert($("#holamundo").is(":visible"));
});
```

```css
button {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>¿Está "Hola Mundo" visible?</button>

<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>

<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

¿Existe alguna función propia o cómo se haría en JavaScript/jQuery para detectar si un elemento está visible Y en la ventana de visualización?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podríamos validar esto accediendo primero a los valores de la "ventana de visualización" , para esto se hace uso de [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) del objeto `window` para saber cuando se desplazó hacía abajo y el limite lo obtenemos de la suma del valor devuelvo por `scrollTop` **+** `height` de la ventana

Luego tendríamos que realizar el mismo procedimiento para el `elemento` , para esto emplearemos [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) para las coordenadas y acceder a la propiedad `top` para  luego obtener la altura del elemento también con [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Ya con estos valores validaríamos comparando , la función quedaría así:

```js
function esVisible(elem){
    /* Ventana de Visualización*/
    var posTopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var posButView = posTopView + $(window).height();
    /* Elemento a validar*/
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    /* Comparamos los dos valores tanto del elemento como de la ventana*/
    return ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) || (elemTop >posTopView && elemTop< posButView));
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('holamundo');
  console.log(esVisible(ele));
});
```

```css
button {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>¿Está "Hola Mundo" visible?</button>
<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

**Update**

Como recomendación de @Alvaro Montoro , Con el ejemplo anterior funcionaría pero [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) no tomará en cuenta el `padding` como sí lo hace [outerheight](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

```js
function esVisible(elem){
    /* Ventana de Visualización*/
    var posTopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var posButView = posTopView + $(window).height();
    /* Elemento a validar*/
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    /* Comparamos los dos valores tanto del elemento como de la ventana*/
    return ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) || (elemTop >posTopView && elemTop< posButView));
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('holamundo');
  console.log(esVisible(ele));
});
```

```css
button {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
#holamundo{
    padding: 120px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>¿Está "Hola Mundo" visible?</button>

<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>

<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

Ejemplo empleando solo `JavaScript`

```js
function esVisible(elem){
    var posTopView = window.scrollY;
    var posButView = posTopView + window.innerHeight;
    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + elem.offsetHeight;
    return ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) || (elemTop >posTopView && elemTop< posButView));
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ele = document.getElementById('holamundo');
    console.log(esVisible(ele));
});
```

```css
button {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">¿Está "Hola Mundo" visible?</button>
<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

> [Referencia en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

**Update**

Otra opción sería utilizar la API [IntersectionObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) para saber si el elemento está visible
 o no.

- Crear el objeto de opciones con tres valores `root` , está propiedad determina el elemento donde se validará la visibilidad del elemento a observar,por defecto toma el viewport del navegador
  `rootMargin`, esta propiedad determina el margen que se incluirá en la evaluación de la visibilidad
  `threshold` , esta propiedad determina el porcentaje de visibilidad que se desea observar, el valor por defecto es 0 es decir que tan pronto como sea visible (1px mínimo),
  y 1 cuando el elemento esté completamente visible. esta propiedad se pueden pasar más de 1 parámetro, revisar la documentación. :)
- Crear la instancia de `IntersectionObserver`, como primer parámetro un callback y como segundo parámetro el objeto de opciones
- Asignar el observer al o los elementos a evaluar. Para el ejemplo solo uno con el id `holamundo`

Dentro del callback tendrá el parámetro entries que hará referencia a los elementos observados, *(el ejemplo el elemento sería el indice 0)*, a través 
de `isIntersecting` verificamos si está visible teniendo en cuenta las opciones, a partir de eso podemos realizar acciones según sea el caso.

```js
function callback(entries,observer){
  if(entries[0].isIntersecting){//verificamos si actualmente es visible
    console.log("El elemento ya está visible...");
  }else{
    console.log("El elemento no es visible.");
  }
}
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {});

const element = document.querySelector('#holamundo');
observer.observe(element);
```

```css
.boxMargin {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border : 1px solid #aec;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxMargin"></div>
<div class="boxMargin"></div>
<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>
<div class="boxMargin"></div>
<div class="boxMargin"></div>
```

Comment: Esta solución parece tener algún problema. Si muevo un poco el scroll, el elemento se sigue viendo, pero obtengo `false`. Ejemplo: http://i.imgur.com/sfR4uIS.gif

Comment: Crei que el problema es que sólo comparas la parte de arriba del elemento, pero no la parte baja. Cambiando la lógica para que incluya las dos parece funcionar: `return ((elemTop > posTopView && elemTop < posButView) || 
            (elemBottom > posTopView && elemBottom < posButView) )`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en teoría funciona. ¿Cree que se puede mejorar algo la función? o algún caso extraordinario se le escapa a dicha función? Ah y gracias por la observación no me había fijado bien en ese detalle.

Comment: Se ve bien. Lo único que consideraría quizás sería usar `innerHeight` o `outerHeight` para que se incluyera el padding. Pero eso sería para casos más particulares

Comment: Gracias por el update @Dev.Joel, con eso soluciono el problema

Answer (score 2):

Yo hice un modulo de npm (disponible en la cdn [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/scroll-utility)) llamado [scroll-utility](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/scroll-utility) que anade muchas facilidades para trabajar con el scroll, incluyendo saber si un elemento esta visible dentro de otro o en la ventana.
Es libre de dependencias, por lo que no necesita de jQuery para funcionar.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
const relativePosition = new ScrollUtility.Scroll().getRelativeElementPosition("#holamundo")
let text = "" 
if (relativePosition < -1) {
  text = "#holamundo no esta visible (arriba del viewport)"
}
if (relativePosition > -1 && relativePosition < 0) {
  text = "#holamundo esta parcialmente visible (pegado arriba)"
}
if (relativePosition > 0 && relativePosition < 1) {
  text = "#holamundo esta completamente visible"
  if (relativePosition > 0.4 && relativePosition < 0.6) {
    text = "#holamundo esta casi centrado en el viewport"
  }
}
if (relativePosition > 1 && relativePosition < 2) {
  text = "#holamundo esta parcialmente visible (pegado abajo)"
}
if (relativePosition > 2) {
  text = "#holamundo no esta visible (debajo del viewport)"
}
alert(text)
});
```

```css
button {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 800px;
}

#holamundo {
  background: gray;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scroll-utility@4.0.0/dist/scroll-utility.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>¿Está "Hola Mundo" visible?</button>

<div id="holamundo">Hola Mundo</div>

<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```