# Saber la posicion de un elemento respecto al scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Como puedo saber cuando se escrollea la posicion de un elemento respecto a la posicion del scroll? Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```js
const elements = [];
 for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
     elements.push(document.getElementById(`p${i}`));
 }
 window.onscroll = () => {
     console.log("scroll event emmited");
     for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        console.log(elements[i].id + " " + elements[i].scrollTop);
     }
 }
```

```html
<p id="p0">
    Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p1">
    Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p2">
    Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p3">
    las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p4">
    Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p5">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p6">
    Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p7">
    porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
</p> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <p id="p8">
    condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. , leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</p>
```

Comment: Puede que su pregunta esté relacionada con esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81507/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-elemento-est%C3%A1-visible-en-la-ventana-de-visualizaci%C3%B3n) anteriormente formulada

Comment: @Dev.Joel Si esta relacionada, pero tanto la pregunta como la repuesta hacen uso de jquery. Podrias traducir la respuesta de tal forma que solo se use javascript, incluso si marcan esta respuesta como duplicada?

Comment: si se marca como duplicada debería añadir la respuesta de solo Js en la otra.

Comment: @Dev.Joel por mi vale

Comment: ya agregué la parte de solo JavaScript espero sea de ayuda. saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He editado un poco el código original de esta [respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20613779/2097224):

Version **JavaScript**:

```js
var prev_id;

document.getElementById('main').onscroll = function(){
    
    var element_height = 200;

    var section = document.getElementById('section');

    // Representa el tamaño de un elemento y su posición relativa a la ventana gráfica
    var screenPosition = section.getBoundingClientRect();  

    // Recogemos el valor top y lo convertimos en números positivos
    var positive =  Math.abs(screenPosition.top);

    var divided = positive / element_height;
    var round = Math.round(divided);

    // Cogemos el id del elemento cual es visible actualmente
    var current_element_id = section.children[round].id;

    if (current_element_id != prev_id) {
 
      prev_id = current_element_id;
      
      console.log(current_element_id);
    }
};
```

```css
main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;   
    background-color:#cdcdcd;
    overflow: auto;
}

section {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

p {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
    <section id="section">
        <p id="p0">
             Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p> 
        <p id="p1">
            Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p> 
        <p id="p2">
            Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y 
            han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, 
            y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por
        </p>
        <p id="p3">
            las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.
            Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p>
        <p id="p4">
            Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y
            han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables,
            y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no 
            debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no
        </p>
        <p id="p5">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
            Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        </p>
        <p id="p6">
            Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
            imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
        </p>
        <p id="p7">
            porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
            feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
        </p>
        <p id="p8">
            condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
            blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. , leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
        </p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Version **jQuery**:

```js
var prev_id;

$('main').scroll(function(){
    
    var element_height = 200;
    var offset = $('section').offset(); // Obtener las coordenadas actuales
    // Recogemos el valor top y lo convertimos en números positivos
    var positive =  Math.abs(offset.top);
    // Divide la distancia con la altura del elemento
    var divided = positive / element_height; 
    var round = Math.round(divided);

    var current_element = $('section').children().eq(round);
    
    // Elige el elemento cual es visible actualmente
    var id = current_element.attr('id');

    // Muestra el id si no coincide con el id anterior
    if (id != prev_id) {
 
      prev_id = id;
      
      console.log(id);
    }
});
```

```css
main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;   
    background-color:#cdcdcd;
    overflow: auto;
}

section {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

p {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
    <section>
        <p id="p0">
             Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p> 
        <p id="p1">
            Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p> 
        <p id="p2">
            Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y 
            han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, 
            y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por
        </p>
        <p id="p3">
            las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.
            Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: 
            Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
        </p>
        <p id="p4">
            Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y
            han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables,
            y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no 
            debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no
        </p>
        <p id="p5">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
            Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        </p>
        <p id="p6">
            Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
            imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
        </p>
        <p id="p7">
            porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
            feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
        </p>
        <p id="p8">
            condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
            blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. , leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
        </p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect tiene en cuenta el margin y el padding?