# ¿Como puedo comprobar que un elemento esta oculto o no con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Se que se puede cambiar la *visibilidad* de un elemento en la pagina web con Jquery con los metodos `.hide()` para ocultarlo o `.show()` para hacerlo visible 
 pero como puedo saber cuando el elemento esta oculto o es visible? es decir cuando tiene la propiedad `hide`o no.

Comment: Utiliza el pseudo selector `:visible` `$("#elemento").is(":visible")`, te devolverá `true` o `false`. [Aquí](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) la documentación

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo saber si un elemento está visible con jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-elemento-est%c3%a1-visible-con-jquery), deberías darte cuenta cuando creas una pregunta las preguntas relacionados...